# C++ Non-destructible classes

Tags: c++

Is there any way in C++ to create class within a function, and then prevent it from destructing?
like

```
class someclass {
public:
int x;
someclass() { x = 0; };
}
someclass::x;
```

and then somewhere

```
someclass * somefunction()
{
someclass somecl ();
return &somecl;
}
```

So we call function 'somefunction' and get pointer to class for later using. I need it to exist as long as program runs/it destructed by other function. Is there any way to do it without storing it inside arrays or vectors?

Comment: You mean objects, not classes. You don't create classes at run-time in C++, you create objects, and there are no pointers to classes but to objects (or functions). That's different than, say, Java, where classes themselves are also run-time objects. In C++, "create class within function" sounds like you want to define a class inside of a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to allocate the memory on the heap and then `delete` the memory when you are done.

```
someclass * somefunction()
{
    return new someclass();
}

int main()
{
    someclass * myclass = somefunction();
    // do stuff with myclass
    delete myclass;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @jammer312 Its a good answer, and correct, but I feel compelled to welcome you to C++ with a warning: you gotta remember to have clear ownership (aka whose job is it to call delete myclass?). else memory leaks and segfaults abound!I personally find returning by value or passing the (allready allocated) pointer make this clear, but you can also use smart pointers if you have them available.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if what you're looking for is a way to define an object once and only once, returning a pointer to the same object each time, or to create a factory function that returns the a newly constructed object each time.  If it's the second, look at previous answers.  If it's the first, check out `static` variables.  As an example, you could write

```
someclass * somefunction()
{
    static someclass somecl ();
    return &somecl;
}
```

This ensures that `somecl` is only defined once, when the function is initially run and that it will be alive until your program exits.  (For a more precise description of the order of cleanup for `static` variables, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sb61xd.aspx).)

Comment: To repeat an important bit in this answer- C++ will automatically destroy this variable when the program ends, you should not to destroy it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could create it on the heap rather than the stack:

```
someclass * somefunction()
{ 
   return new someclass();
}
```

You may also want to consider returning it in a smart pointer, to explicitly transfer ownership and control its lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

```
someclass * somefunction()
{
    return new somecl ();
}
```

You were very close :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are driving at, I can imagine two different use cases where you would want to make a class indestructible.

---

Case 1: Singleton
The idiomatic way to do this, is to use a static instance of the class that's declared within an accessor function:

```
class Foo {
    public:
        static Foo& globalFoo();
    private:
        Foo() {};
        ~Foo() {};
};

Foo& Foo::globalFoo() {
    static Foo myFoo;
    return myFoo;
}

int main() {
    Foo& myFoo = Foo::globalFoo();
}
```

That way, it is impossible for other code to either construct or destruct any instance of `Foo`, it can only use the one instance that's provided by the `globalFoo()` function.

---

Case 2: Wrapped allocation/deallocation
If you just want to force allocation/deallocation to happen via certain static functions, you only need to make both the constructor and the destructor private (just as in the singleton case), and add static functions to the interface for allocation/deallocation:

```
class Foo {
    public:
        static Foo* makeFoo();
        static void destroyFoo(Foo* aFoo);
    private:
        Foo() {};
        ~Foo() {};
};

Foo* Foo::makeFoo() {
    return new Foo();
}

void Foo::destroyFoo(Foo* aFoo) {
    delete aFoo;
}

int main() {
    Foo* myFoo = Foo::makeFoo();
    Foo::destroyFoo(myFoo);
}
```